# rust nalgebra set a block in matrix to rotation?

Tags: c++, rust, linear-algebra, eigen, nalgebra

I am trying to set the upper left block of a 4X4 matrix to a rotation matrix.

I have tried different flavours of:

```rust
    let mut mat = Mat4::identity();
    mat.set_column(3, &Vec4::new(trans.x, trans.y, trans.z, 1.0));

    let slice = &mat.slice((0,0), (3,3));
    slice = &rot.to_rotation_matrix().matrix().slice((0,0), (3,3));
```

Each one fails to compile with a different error because the types don't match.

The equivalent code in eigen that i am trying to replicate is:

```cpp
        Eigen::Quaternionf rotation = joint_animation.SampleRotation(t);
        Eigen::Vector3f translation = joint_animation.SampleTranslation(t);
        Eigen::Vector3f scale = joint_animation.SampleScaling(t);

        Eigen::Matrix4f t_mat = skin.joint_matrices[i];

        t_mat.block(0, 0, 3, 3) = (rotation).toRotationMatrix();

        t_mat.row(0).head<3>() *= scale(0);
        t_mat.row(1).head<3>() *= scale(1);
        t_mat.row(2).head<3>() *= scale(2);

        t_mat(0, 3) = translation[0];
        t_mat(1, 3) = translation[1];
        t_mat(2, 3) = translation[2];
```

BTW I aliased some nalgebra types:

```rust
pub type Quatf = na::UnitQuaternion<f32>;

pub type Mat2 = na::Matrix2<f32>;
pub type Mat3 = na::Matrix3<f32>;
pub type Mat4 = na::Matrix4<f32>;
```

Comment: It would help if you specify which crate these `Mat4`, `Vec4` come from (`cgmath` maybe?). I assume that `Eigen` comes from the `eigen` crate.

Comment: rust nalgebra, it;s in the title

Comment: Eigen is C++ as stated in the post it comes from the C++ library eigen.

Comment: `nalgebra`, yes, I noticed after posting my comment, but I don't find any `Mat4` [there](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/?search=Mat4).

Comment: I did alias some types, you are right I should have mentioned it, I edited the post